# can't load libgtkmm-3.0.so.1 problem with Photomatix on Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde

After I have installed Photomatix following
[this intructions](https://www.hdrsoft.com/download/photomatix-linux.html).
I wanted to run this program. But i get an error message:

/usr/bin/photomatix-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libgtkmm-3.0.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Any Ideas whats wrong here ?
I spend some time looking on the internet for solutions, but everything i tried did'nt solve this.
I have Kubuntu 16.04 LTS x64 with KDE 5.7.2 on an old Toshiba Tecra a9.

thanks.

Comment: Is libgtkmm installed?  Try installing it: `apt-get install libgtkmm-3.0-1v5`

Comment: yeah it finally worked after I installed the common. Thank you!!